# Vector-Matrix-Multiplication in java with parallel colt

Tags: java, matrix, vector, parallel-processing, colt

I would like to multiply a vector (1 x n) with a matrix (m x n) in java and the library parallel colt. 
I guess I have chosen it because it has parallel in its name. So you are invited to give me other nice matrix librarys in java.

But my problem is particular the vector-matrix-multiplication... I haven't found a seperate method for it on the DenseDoubleMatrix2D class? How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The matrix multiplication can be done by the `DoubleAlgebra` class, which has the overloaded `mult` methods.

- [`mult(DoubleMatrix1D x, DoubleMatrix1D y)`](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/algo/DoubleAlgebra.html#mult(cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix1D,%20cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix1D)), to compute the inner product of two vectors.
- [`mult(DoubleMatrix2D x, DoubleMatrix1D y)`](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/algo/DoubleAlgebra.html#mult(cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D,%20cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix1D)), for matrix-vector multiplication.
- [`mult(DoubleMatrix2D x, DoubleMatrix2D y)`](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/algo/DoubleAlgebra.html#mult(cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D,%20cern.colt.matrix.tdouble.DoubleMatrix2D)), for matrix-matrix multiplication.

Comment: but a vector is a DoubleMatrix1D which can not be the first argument of mult. and you can also not transpose a 1D matrix ...

Comment: @KIC Thank you for pointing that out. Updated the answer to link to the correct method.